Confusion about smoothness and decay of Fourier-like series on a manifold
Let $D$ be a first-order self-adjoint elliptic differential operator acting on sections of a vector bundle $S$ over a closed manifold $M$. Then it is well-known that the various eigenspaces $E_\lambda$ (which by elliptic regularity consist of smooth sections of $S$) of $D$ provide a decomposition of $L^2(S)$ in the sense that
$$L^2(S)=\overline{\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\sigma(D)}E_\lambda},$$
where the direct sum is orthogonal. Thus each section $s\in L^2(S)$ can be written
$$s=\sum_\lambda s_\lambda,$$
where $s_\lambda$ is the orthogonal projection of $s$ onto $E_\lambda$.
In John Roe's book "Elliptic Operators", there is a nice characterisation of the smooth part of $L^2(M)$ via the following proposition:

with the following proof (which is the source of my confusion):

Here the Sobolev space $W^k$ is defined via the norm
$$\|u\|_k^2=\sum_{j=0}^k\|D^ju\|_{L^2}^2.$$
Question: Could someone explain in a bit more detail how the above proof works, i.e. how the alleged convergence is supposed to happen?
Thoughts: Applied to the above decomposition of $s$, the right-hand side becomes
$$\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_\lambda|\lambda|^{2j}\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}^2.$$
Let's say we take $\lambda\geq 1$. Then we are concerned with estimating the term
$$\sum_\lambda|\lambda|^k\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}^2,$$
where the summand is of the form given in Roe's proof. However, knowing only that $\|s_\lambda\|_{L^2}$ decays as $O(\lambda)^{-k}$ for all $k$ does not seem enough to guarantee the convergence of this sum, without knowing more about the distribution of $\lambda$ at least. (I could of course be misinterpreting something and would appreciate a quick pointer if that's the case!)

I believe you are right that the proposition is wrong. Could you construct a compact manifold such that $\dim E_{\le N}=O(e^{CN})$?
